# Adding onBlur Functionality in Forms in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple form build in react js. It has a text area with a submit button. Now I want to add an OnBlur functionality in this form. I tried this in the render method:

```
render() {
        return (
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}> onBlur={this.onBlur}
            <label>
              Name:
              <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
            </label>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
          </form>
        );
      }
```

But this is not working. The original code( from FaceBook Tutorials) is as follows: Please note that I know that I need to bind the onBlur() through these lines: `this.onBlur = this.onBlur.bind(this);`. So that is not an area of Concern.

```
class NameForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `onBlur=<this.onBlur>`? Did you mean `onBlur={this.onBlur}`

Comment: it seems your JSX syntax is incorrect. Replace `onBlur=<this.onBlur>` with `onBlur={this.onBlur}`

Comment: I am sorry for the typing mistakes. Editing has been done. Please review the code.

Comment: Please show an example of what you want it to do onBlur that isn't working.

Comment: @Vagabond What exactly isn't working. Do you have a `handleBlur` method? Try `<form onBlur={this.handleBlur}>` and `console.log` something.